# $not operator is not working inside an $and operator in query

Tags: mongodb

I want to query my database with the following restrictions, for all records where *all* these conditions are true:

- `property` is `propertyID`
- `active` is `true`
- `startDate` is NOT greater than Y
- `endDate` is NOT less than X

I am having a hard time getting MongoDB to accept my `$match`:

```
$match:{
    $and:[
        { property : propertyID },
        { active   : true },
        { $not: { start : {$gte: 1498780800 } } },
        { $not: { end   : {$lte: 1497052800 } } }
    ]
}
```

Right now I am getting the error: **MongoError: unknown top level operator: `$not`**. You might say just do `startDate` less than X and `endDate` less than Y, but this won't work because `startDate` might be greater than X and `endDate` less than Y which is a record I want etc.. which is why that won't work. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

My logic is not correct, this is what I am trying to do...

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't use `start: {$lt: 1498780800}, end: {$gt: 1497052800}` for that part instead.

Comment: They shouldn't have done that. Can you explain here in the comments and give an example `start` and `end` value where it wouldn't work? Or add that info to your question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK My bad, I didn't mean to get rid of it. Re-edited in now.

Comment: @JohnnyHK its really complex, at least in my mind. I cant seem to get the grasp about dates.  Let me make an image that shows exactly what I want.

Comment: @AndrewLi your fix actually worked, but my logic is wrong. I will put an image of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JohnnyHK please have a look at the image - I need the records that are within the X-Y dates.  I just cant seem to create the correct logic, my brain hurts from thinking in dates and $lte $gte :-)

Comment: So if `start` is in between OR `end` is in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got `$not` in the wrong place. Per [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

> *Syntax*: `{ field: { $not: { <operator-expression> } } }`

Thus, `$not` should be used not as a top level operator, the field should be at the top level.

On to the logical side of this problem. You want to select records *where `start` is in between the restricted dates **or** `end` is in between the restricted dates,* there's no reason to use `$not` here. Also, make sure you are checking for greater than the minimum and less than the maximum, not the other way around. Try the following query:

```
$match: {
  $and: [
    { property: propertyID },
    { active: true },
    { $or: [
      { start: { $lte: 1498780800, $gte: 1497052800 } },
      { end: { $lte: 1498780800, $gte: 1497052800 } }
    ] }
  ]
}
```

This will check if either `start` or `end` is in between the restricted dates.